# Why is this a invalid syntax error in Python?

Tags: python

```
import math
# Program intro
def main():
# float print functions for n, A, r

n = float(input('How much time in years do you need to pay back the loan?'))
A = float(input("What is the amount of money you would like to borrow in whole dollars $?"))
r = float(input("What is your desired interest rate in a whole number?"
P = (r + A) / (n * A)
```

why is P = (r + A) / (n * A) a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're missing closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = float(input("What is your desired interest rate in a whole number?"
                                                                      ^
                                                      Missing 2 parenthesis
```

The correct line would look like:

```
r = float(input("What is your desired interest rate in a whole number?"))
```